# No audio through bluetooth speaker

Tags: bluetooth-speaker

I have a thinkpad w530 running 14.10. My speaker is a soundbot. The speaker pairs fine with the laptop, and I can see it as an option under audio output , but no sound comes out. Anyone know how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I had to click on the speaker icon then settings and make sure the blue-tooth one is highlighted. Then it started working.
Randy

Comment: Tried that. Still no audio.